# Height of a paralelogramm

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have the coordinates of the 4 vertexes of a parallelogram.
If i calculate the length of two opposing sides, how do I get the perpendicular distance between them?
Is it just the distance between the 2 side's midpoint?

Answer (score 1):

No the distance between two midpoints is the same as a side, which is not what you want.

The easiest is probably to start by calculating the area of the parallelogram (by taking the length of the cross product of two adjacent sides in 3D, or as a determinant in 2D) and then divide by the length of the side you want to have as base.

Comment: I got the base length already. Should I try to calculate a diagonal?

Comment: No. Just, as I said, divide the area by the known base length. This will give you the height.

Comment: But I don't have the area, I have to find the area, by the base and the height that's my problem :/

Comment: @JohnFire: Who says you have to do it that way? It will be rather more difficult to find the height _without_ getting the area as an intermediate result somewhere. Much easier to call it a day at that point and use the area you've already got, I think.

Comment: Well my teacher was insisting to do it that way, but then if its that hard I guess there is no choice, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If by opposing sides you mean parallel sides, then no, it isn't. That will be the length of the side adjacent to the one you are referring to.

One way would be to find the area of the parallelogram using the coordinates and equate the area to the product of the base and the height. The length of the base can again be found using the coordinates of two adjacent points.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate! Posted just after the other reply

Comment: @JohnFire To get the answer without getting the area, you can find the slope of the base corresponding to the height you need. Then, the slope of the height will be the negative of the reciprocal of the slope of the base. Find the equation of the line passing through a point of the parallelogram which is not a point on the base with this slope and find its point of intersection with the base. The distance between these two points is the height.